# PGFPlots with custom minor ticks

Tags: pgfplots

How do you create a plot with *minor* ticks on the abscissa, when you've customized the major ticks?

[image: Inverse temperature plot with minor ticks on the abscissa]

A MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
T   dT
37.598    2.198 
48.34     1.466 
60.394    1.829
77.515    1.466
85.938    1.832
103.546   1.648
125.092   2.442
154.083   2.000
184.998   1.832
191.498   0.366
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\dataA

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{simple}{%
solid, every mark/.append style={fill=none, line width=0.25pt}, mark=o\\%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=18cm, height=10cm},
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$-1000/T$ (1/K)},
    ylabel={y},
    minor tick num=9,
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=-1.75,
    xtick={-3.5,-3.25,..., -1.75},
    xticklabels={$-3.50$, $-3.25$, $-3.00$, $-2.75$, $-2.50$, $-2.25$, $-2.00$, $-1.75$},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.17)},anchor=north},
    hide y axis,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line*=none,    
    tick align = inside,
    cycle list name= simple]
    \pgfplotsset{every outer x axis line/.style={yshift=-1.5cm}, every tick/.style={yshift=-1.5cm, line width=0.25pt}, every x tick label/.style={yshift=-1.5cm}}
    \addplot+[only marks, white] table [x expr=-1000/(273+\thisrow{T}), y=dT] {\dataA};
\end{axis} 
\begin{axis}[grid=major,
xtick={-3.472222222, -3.095975232, -2.680965147, -2.364066194, -2.114164905, -1.912045889},
xticklabels={15, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250},
xmin=-3.5, xmax=-1.7,
ymin=0.1, ymax=10,
minor x tick num=10,
xminorticks=true,
restrict y to domain=-1:10,
enlargelimits=false,
clip=false,
axis on top,
tick align = inside,
cycle list name= simple,
ymode=log,
log basis y={10},
yminorgrids,
xlabel={Temperature (C)},
ylabel={Temperature Rise Rate (C/min)},
ytick scale label code/.code={},  
]
\addplot+[only marks] table [x expr=-1000/(273+\thisrow{T}), y=dT] {\dataA}; %\addlegendentry{Data set 1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The following image shows what I've been able to produce with more verbose code (i.e., not MWE).

[image: Plot generated with PGFPlots, without minor ticks on abscissa]

Comment: This is an inverse temperature plot, similar to Arrhenius plots. The xtick values represent -1000/(T+273). For 50 °C, the corresponding xtick should be -1000/(50+273) = -3.09. Thanks for catching the 11 ticks. I only want 10! I've reduced the code as much as I believe I can. Any further suggestions to minimize the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but I just used

```
minor xtick={-3.412969283, -3.355704698, -3.300330033, -3.246753247,
-3.194888179, -3.144654088, -3.048780488, -3.003003003, -2.958579882,
-2.915451895, -2.873563218, -2.83286119, -2.793296089, -2.754820937, 
-2.717391304, -2.645502646, -2.610966057, -2.577319588, -2.544529262, 
-2.512562814, -2.481389578, -2.450980392, -2.421307506, -2.392344498, 
-2.336448598, -2.309468822, -2.283105023, -2.257336343, -2.232142857, 
-2.207505519, -2.183406114, -2.159827214, -2.136752137, -2.092050209, 
-2.070393375, -2.049180328, -2.028397566, -2.008032129, -1.988071571,
-1.968503937, -1.949317739, -1.930501931, -1.893939394, -1.876172608, 
-1.858736059, -1.841620626, -1.824817518, -1.808318264, -1.792114695, 
-1.776198934, -1.76056338},
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
T   dT
37.598    2.198 
48.34     1.466 
60.394    1.829
69.061    1.770
77.515    1.466
85.938    1.832
94.482    1.708
103.546   1.648
113.22    2.196
125.092   2.442
140.106   2.562
154.083   2.000
171.204   3.724
184.998   1.832
189.606   0.488
191.498   0.366
193.39    0.306
194.733   0.610
195.801   0.305
196.747   0.121
197.846   0.062
\end{filecontents}


\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\dataA

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{simple}{%
solid, every mark/.append style={fill=none, line width=0.25pt}, mark=o\\%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=18cm, height=10cm},
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dotted,black!80}}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,black!60}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=1pt}}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$-1000/T$ (\si{\per\kelvin})},
    ylabel={y},
    color=black,
    minor tick num=9,
    xmin=-3.5,
    xmax=-1.75,
    x axis line style={black},
    xtick style={black},
    xtick={-3.5,-3.25,..., -1.75},
    xticklabels={$-3.50$, $-3.25$, $-3.00$, $-2.75$, $-2.50$, $-2.25$, $-2.00$, $-1.75$},
    xticklabel style={black},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.17)},anchor=north},
    hide y axis,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line*=none,    
    tick align = inside,
    cycle list name= simple]
    \pgfplotsset{every outer x axis line/.style={yshift=-1.5cm}, every tick/.style={yshift=-1.5cm, line width=0.25pt}, every x tick label/.style={yshift=-1.5cm}}
    \addplot+[only marks, white] table [x expr=-1000/(273+\thisrow{T}), y=dT] {\dataA}; %\addlegendentry{Data set 1}
\end{axis} 
\begin{axis}[grid=major,
every y tick/.style={black},
every x tick/.style={black},
xtick={-3.472222222, -3.095975232, -2.680965147, -2.364066194, -2.114164905, -1.912045889},
xticklabels={15, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250},
minor xtick={-3.412969283, -3.355704698, -3.300330033, -3.246753247,
-3.194888179, -3.144654088, -3.048780488, -3.003003003, -2.958579882,
-2.915451895, -2.873563218, -2.83286119, -2.793296089, -2.754820937, 
-2.717391304, -2.645502646, -2.610966057, -2.577319588, -2.544529262, 
-2.512562814, -2.481389578, -2.450980392, -2.421307506, -2.392344498, 
-2.336448598, -2.309468822, -2.283105023, -2.257336343, -2.232142857, 
-2.207505519, -2.183406114, -2.159827214, -2.136752137, -2.092050209, 
-2.070393375, -2.049180328, -2.028397566, -2.008032129, -1.988071571,
-1.968503937, -1.949317739, -1.930501931, -1.893939394, -1.876172608, 
-1.858736059, -1.841620626, -1.824817518, -1.808318264, -1.792114695, 
-1.776198934, -1.76056338},
xmin=-3.5, 
xmax=-1.7452,
ymin=0.1,
ymax=10,
minor x tick num=10,
xminorticks=true,
restrict y to domain=-1:10,
enlargelimits=false,
clip=false,
axis on top,
tick align = inside,
cycle list name= simple,
ymode=log,
log basis y={10},
yminorgrids,
xlabel={Temperature (\si{\celsius})},
ylabel={Temperature Rise Rate (\si{\celsius\per\minute})},
ytick scale label code/.code={},  
]
\addplot+[only marks] table [x expr=-1000/(273+\thisrow{T}), y=dT] {\dataA}; %\addlegendentry{Data set 1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]